# How to fix "-scipy.misc has no attribute "imresize""

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy

I have some code from my friend. 
He run it smoothly but I encounter

`module **scipy.misc** has no attribute *imresize*`

I'm searching, installed Pillow (PIL), scipy, scikit,.. but dont work

I asked my friend but he forgot what he has installed.

Answer (score 24):

If you check [the documentation for `scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) from many recent versions of `scipy`, you'll find the following line up at the top:

> `imresize` is deprecated! `imresize` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.3.0. Use Pillow instead: `numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())`.

The 1.3.0 release happened yesterday, so if you downloaded `scipy` on your system today, you may have got the new version, which won't have access to that function any longer. The documentation I quoted above suggests a code fragment (using `numpy` and `PIL`) that should work as an alternative.

Comment: what is `Image` in your suggested code? Do I need to import it from somewhere?

Comment: `Image` is the main module from `PIL` (AKA the fork `Pillow`). Use `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: or install the previous available version, but I wouldn't recommend it, except if there is no other way - `pip uninstall scipy` , `pip install scipy==1.2.2`

Answer (score 12):

scipy.misc.imresize is depricated.

There are two alternatives

1. As pointed by @Bickknght we can use PIL (Pillow)library.

   ```
   from PIL import Image
   numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())
   ```
2. Using Skimage

   ```
   from skimage.transform import resize
   from skimage import data
   image = data.camera()
   resize(image, (100, 100))
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Install scipy(1.2.2) this will work.

```
pip install scipy==1.2.2
```

If still not work --> install pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```

scipy.misc.imresize - Resize an image [requires Pillow]

**OR**

`help('scipy.misc.imresize')`

```
scipy.misc.imresize = imresize(*args, **kwds)
`imresize` is deprecated!
`imresize` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.3.0.
Use Pillow instead: ``numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())``.

Resize an image.

This function is only available if Python Imaging Library (PIL) is installed.
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
pip install scipy==1.2.2
```